# Should I propose the new tag "rundeck"?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I would like to propose the creation of a "rundeck" tag, but I am not sure how popular a keyword should be before proposing a tag.

Though it only has 31 results when searched for (and at least one related under a mis-spelling of "run deck"), this is more than some tags I have seen. Most related questions and answers are from within the last year and the below Google search trend also indicates a rising occurrence of the term:

[image]

For example, I've just edited and answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461446/execute-windows-scripts-from-a-remote-rundeck-server/18808923), which I believe could benefit from the tag.

**UPDATE:**

Since studying the [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/197141) more, I have updated the attached image to better illustrate the important points.

Comment: One does not usually "propose" a tag - they either ask a new question with that tag, or edit the tag into existing questions.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, I received the following alert `Creating the new tag 'rundeck' requires at least 1500 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead` and had seen somewhere on Meta advising to request it here if reputation did not suffice

Comment: Actually, the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It isn't a programming issue. To my eyes, it looks like a system administration issue and as such more suitable to Server Fault.

Comment: @Oded, I can see where that can be applicable, yet there are a wealth of Jenkins (11k+) and other CI/automation tool questions within SO. Server Fault can sometimes dismiss questions due to the site being for professionals only, as opposed to SO, which the About page defines as "for professional and enthusiast programmers". Many DevOps tools are now utilized by developers, professional or enthusiast, in order to deploy code and I could see many questions as relevant within SO.

Comment: @LeonStafford - I admit that I have no idea what `rundeck` is - all I can see is a question about a server and managing it in Windows. If it were clear that `rundeck` _is_ a software development tool, fine, but it very much isn't clear to me.

Comment: @Oded, I agree that particular question mentions no code. I would compare it to one like this about [restarting Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072700/jenkins-manual-restart). I think that while there is no dedicated [Dev Ops](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44390/devops) site, there will continue to be many questions about these tools that seem fitting within SO. Mind, you, I'm biased to push the point to try and build up some rep ;)

Comment: Again - it really is about what `rundeck` is and what it is used for. If it isn't a common tool within software development (which Jenkins **is**), then it isn't on-topic.

Comment: I would assert that Rundeck is a common tool now. It is also often used in conjunction with Jenkins and other tools such as Chef, Puppet, etc. It's a great piece of kit!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, users are prevented from proposing an edit with a tag addition, if the tag doesn't exist already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done.

After taking a look at rundeck.org and following your comments on its utility in software development, I agree that it is a software tool.

Added the tag to the question - by all means, retag other relevant questions.

Comment: Thanks Oded! I'll take it upon myself to retag the questions now that I've put you through all that :)

Comment: @LeonStafford - I retagged a few questions that specifically ask about rundeck.